# Rails Engines - is it possible to add associations to the model in a container model like Forem does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

This Question is more than a single question so breaking it up into more managable pieces: [Rails Engines - simple possible engine to (1) add a model and (2) add the association in the containing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349322/simple-possible-engine-to-1-add-a-model-and-2-add-the-association-in-the-con)

I am testing out building a Rails engine and am curious whether I can add an association to a specific model in the hosting / container app.

The hosting app has a user model class (yes, this will never chnage) and my engine is called abc and I have a model in my  engine called posts (so Abc::Post and the table is abc_posts). I'd like to add to the User class in the main app this association. As a drop dead simple try, I created in my engine:

```
#located in the engine at: abc/app/models/user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :abc_posts
end
```

the post file:

```
#located in the engine at: abc/app/models/abc/post.rb
module Abc
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :body, :header, :user_id
    belongs_to :user
  end
end
```

Via rails console, I was able to create records in the table (easy part) but the User class doesn't know about the association. Any ideas on how to get this done?

thx in advance

**edit 1**

I've tried using the decorators gem as used in forem (see comment below) and have this file:

```
#abc/app/decorators/lib/abc/user_class_decorator.rb
Object.const_get(User).class_eval do
  has_many :abc_posts, :class_name => "Abc::Post", :foreign_key => "user_id"
end
```

I have included the decorators via:
lib/abc.rb

```
require "decorators"
```

but his doesn't seem to be working. Not sure if this is right strategy or whether syntax is even correct.

Comment: Are you getting some errors? Have you tried:
`has_many :abc_posts, class_name: "Abc::Post"`?

Comment: hmm.. I did try that earlier and just retested; it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I feel like somehow I need to get a reference to this user class and add this method. https://github.com/radar/forem does something like this but a lot of the code is opaque to me right now.

Comment: prob something very similar to this: https://github.com/radar/forem/blob/master/app/decorators/lib/forem/user_class_decorator.rb

Answer (score 1):

That should do the job - specify the class for the relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :class_name => "Abc::Post"
end
```

Hmmm, I created an example and it does work ...

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Abc::Child"
end
```

The module with the class Child is in the model/abc.

```
module Abc
  class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent
  end
end
```

Here the journal

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > Parent.create(:name => 'Mr Daddy')
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (9.4ms)  INSERT INTO "parents" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 03 May 2013 10:49:54 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Mr Daddy"], ["updated_at", Fri, 03 May 2013 10:49:54 UTC +00:00]]
(1.9ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Parent id: 1, name: "Mr Daddy", created_at: "2013-05-03 10:49:54", updated_at: "2013-05-03 10:49:54"> 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > Abc::Child.create(:name => 'Sammy boy', :parent => Parent.first )
Parent Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "parents".* FROM "parents" ORDER BY "parents"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (117.3ms)  INSERT INTO "children" ("created_at", "name", "parent_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 03 May 2013 10:49:58 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Sammy boy"], ["parent_id", 1], ["updated_at", Fri, 03 May 2013 10:49:58 UTC +00:00]]
(2.1ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Abc::Child id: 1, name: "Sammy boy", parent_id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-03 10:49:58", updated_at: "2013-05-03 10:49:58"> 
1.9.3-p194 :003 > Abc::Child.create(:name => 'Milly girl', :parent => Parent.first )
Parent Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "parents".* FROM "parents" ORDER BY "parents"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "children" ("created_at", "name", "parent_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 03 May 2013 10:50:15 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Milly girl"], ["parent_id", 1], ["updated_at", Fri, 03 May 2013 10:50:15 UTC +00:00]]
(2.7ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Abc::Child id: 2, name: "Milly girl", parent_id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-03 10:50:15", updated_at: "2013-05-03 10:50:15"> 
1.9.3-p194 :004 > Parent.first.children.first
Parent Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "parents".* FROM "parents" ORDER BY "parents"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Abc::Child Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = ? ORDER BY "children"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["parent_id", 1]]
=> #<Abc::Child id: 1, name: "Sammy boy", parent_id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-03 10:49:58", updated_at: "2013-05-03 10:49:58"> 
1.9.3-p194 :005 > Parent.first.children.last
Parent Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "parents".* FROM "parents" ORDER BY "parents"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Abc::Child Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = ? ORDER BY "children"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["parent_id", 1]]
=> #<Abc::Child id: 2, name: "Milly girl", parent_id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-03 10:50:15", updated_at: "2013-05-03 10:50:15"> 
1.9.3-p194 :006 > Parent.first.children.count
Parent Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "parents".* FROM "parents" ORDER BY "parents"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = ?  [["parent_id", 1]]
=> 2
```