# Rails Engines - simple possible engine to (1) add a model and (2) add the association in the containing class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I am trying to write my first engine but am having problems with the following scenario. In the host app, I will have  User model (this is guaranteed so in the engine I can refer to User class rather than some level of indirection) which has a name. In the engine, I will have a post model and need to create an association between the post model and the user model in the containing app.

```
>rails plugin new abc --mountable
...
>rails g model Post header:string body:text user_id:integer
```

... edit the post file:

```
module Abc
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :body, :header, :user_id
    belongs_to :user

    def self.say_hello
      puts "hello: " + Object.const_get(User).to_s
    end
  end
end
```

How do I access the user model in the containining class to add the following?

```
has_many :abc_posts, class: "Abc::Post"
```

I have tried every variation of having in the engine (at app/models/ app/models/abc etc....):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :abc_posts, class: "Abc::Post"
end
```

but to no avail. How do I get this to work?

thx in advance